# Collapsing bootstrap menu on click in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a navigation for my website in reactJS and using the MDBoostrap librabry https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/navigation/compositions/

But I have a problem that whenever it is in mobile view and I press a button it does not collapse back to previous state but goes to another page. My code so far is

```
class FixedNavbarExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          collapse: false,
      };
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({
        collapse: !this.state.collapse,
      });
  }

  render() {
    const bgPink = {backgroundColor: '#e91e63'}
    const container = {height: 1300}
    return(
      <div>
        <Router>
          <header>
            <MDBNavbar style={bgPink} dark expand="md" scrolling fixed="top">
              <MDBNavbarBrand href="/">
                  <strong>Navbar</strong>
              </MDBNavbarBrand>
              <MDBNavbarToggler onClick={ this.onClick } />
              <MDBCollapse isOpen = { this.state.collapse } navbar>
                <MDBMDBNavbarNav left>
                  <MDBNavItem active>
                      <MDBNavLink to="#">Home</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                      <MDBNavLink to="#">Features</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                      <MDBNavLink to="#">Pricing</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to="#">Options</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                </MDBMDBNavbarNav>
                <MDBNavbarNav right>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to="#"><MDBIcon fab icon="facebook-f" /></MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to="#"><MDBIcon fab icon="twitter" /></MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to="#"><MDBIcon fab icon="instagram" /></MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                </MDBNavbarNav>
              </MDBCollapse>
            </MDBNavbar>
          </header>
        </Router>
        <MDBContainer style={container} className="text-center mt-5 pt-5">
          <h2>This Navbar is fixed</h2>
          <h5>It will always stay visible on the top, even when you scroll down</h5>
          <br/>
          <p>Full page intro with background image will be always displayed in full screen mode, regardless of device</p>
        </MDBContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FixedNavbarExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ok I just added onClick={ this.onClick } to MDBNavItem.